# How can you cast Redux state to an Angular view Observable?

Tags: redux, observable, angular8, rxjs6

I'm using a Redux Store within an Angular app to hold application state.

But in my view I want to assign this Redux store state to an Observable$ variable that the Angular view can bind to and update as state changes.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

.....

// Using RxJS operator to cast Redux store state to an Observable
public viewData: any[] = [];
this.viewData$ = of(this.store.getState());
```

But when I try to bind `viewData` to the view in an ngFor I get an error stating the viewData is not in the correct format of an array `..ngFor didn't expect [Object object]`

```
<div *ngFor="let data of viewData| async"> 
    <div>{{ data }}</div>
  </div>
```

`Question`

How can you cast Redux store state to an Angular Observable using RxJs operators?

I know if I was to use NgRx Store I could just wrap it in a store.select like `viewData = this.store.select(store.getState);` but *Redux* doesn't have an equivalent `select` method to cast state as an Observable.
See: https://ngrx.io/api/store/select

Answer (score 0):

viewData is not in the correct format of an array ..ngFor didn't expect [Object object] shows that you are trying to iterate over an object with an array method. Check that your returned data is of type array, if not convert the result to an array.